# Regex for " . . . . ." in R

Tags: r, regex

I'm trying to set up a scraper for northeast Ohio election results. For most of the counties, election results look a lot like [this](http://eresults.co.geauga.oh.us/):

```
      Member of Council BURTON VILLAGE
      (Vote for not more than )  4
          (WITH 1 OF 1 PRECINCTS COUNTED)
       Thomas F. Blair, Sr..  .  .  .  .  .  .       173   18.23
       Vicki L. Blair.  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .       120   12.64
       Ann Therese Bullard .  .  .  .  .  .  .       140   14.75
       Bonnie Lou Richards .  .  .  .  .  .  .       171   18.02
       Craig Ronyak  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .       168   17.70
       Ruth V. Spanos.  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .       177   18.65
```

So, what I want to do is be able pull out the names of candidates, then the vote count. However, I'm having trouble figuring out how to get R to parse different parts of regular expressions, particularly an arbitrary number of spaces and periods between the name and the number of votes.

So if I plug this in, it works:

```
tblair <- lapply(mytxtfiles, function(i) {
  j <- paste0(scan(i, what = character()), collapse = " ")
  regmatches(j, gregexpr("(?<=Blair, Sr.. . . . . . . ).*?(?=\n* )",       
  j, perl=TRUE))
})
```

If I plug this in, I get an error message about invalid escaped characters and unexpected parentheses:

```
tblair <- lapply(mytxtfiles, function(i) {
  j <- paste0(scan(i, what = character()), collapse = " ")
  regmatches(j, gregexpr("(?<=Blair, Sr.(\\s\\.)*).*?(?=\n* )", j, perl=TRUE))
})
```

Thanks!

Comment: Not clear about the expected `str1 <- "Thomas F. Blair, Sr..  .  .  .  .  .  .       173   18.23"; sub("(\\.\\s+)*(\\s[0-9. ]+)", "\\2", str1)#
[1] "Thomas F. Blair, Sr. 173   18.23"`

Comment: You might try another tactic: treat it as a fixed width file, then trim off the periods and spaces.

Comment: What is the eexpected result? Try `regmatches(j, gregexpr("Blair, Sr\\.[\\s.]*\\K.*?(?=\\R* )", j, perl=TRUE))`

Comment: Or even [`"Blair, Sr\\.[\\h.]*\\K\\d+"`](https://regex101.com/r/9IHtK7/1).

Comment: That worked! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Starting with:

```
x <- c("Thomas F. Blair, Sr..  .  .  .  .  .  .       173   18.23",
       "Vicki L. Blair.  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .       120   12.64",
       "Ann Therese Bullard .  .  .  .  .  .  .       140   14.75",
       "Bonnie Lou Richards .  .  .  .  .  .  .       171   18.02",
       "Craig Ronyak  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .       168   17.70",
       "Ruth V. Spanos.  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .       177   18.65")
```

I'd try `extract` from the "tidyverse":

```
library(tidyverse)
data.frame(x) %>% 
  extract(x, into = c("Person", "Count", "Percent"), 
          regex = "(.*)\\s+(\\d+)\\s+(\\d.*)", convert = TRUE) %>%
  mutate(Person = trimws(gsub("\\.  .*$", "", Person)))
#                 Person Count Percent
# 1 Thomas F. Blair, Sr.   173   18.23
# 2       Vicki L. Blair   120   12.64
# 3  Ann Therese Bullard   140   14.75
# 4  Bonnie Lou Richards   171   18.02
# 5         Craig Ronyak   168   17.70
# 6       Ruth V. Spanos   177   18.65
```